# How can I see in which albums is a photo?

Tags: macos, ios, photos.app

Photos.app — I can't find a way to see in which albums a photo is in, neither on iOS or macOS.

This seems such a basic thing that should be there but I can't find how to do it.
When a photo is selected, I would expect an indication on whichever albums in the sidebar the photo is in.
At least show it on the info box on mac or info pane on iOS.

But right now I can't figure out if it should be there and I'm seeing a bug, the functionality isn't there, or if I'm too stupid to figure it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't, at least not out of the box. But there is an AppleScript described in https://robservatory.com/show-albums-a-given-photos-photo-has-been-added-to/ (or actually in https://discussions.apple.com/docs/DOC-9261) which solves the problem, kind of.

> To use the script, paste it all into AppleScript Editor and save it as an application (or you can just run it in AppleScript Editor). In Photos, create a top-level album (I named mine Find Albums Photo Is In), and place the photo you want to know about into that album. Leave it selected, then run the AppleScript. You’ll see one dialog stating what photo is being used, then after a bit, you should see a results dialog

```
-- from https://robservatory.com/show-albums-a-given-photos-photo-has-been-added-to/
tell application "Photos"
    activate
    -- Add the photo you want to search for to a top level album as the first item in the album

    set resultcaption to "Searching for: "
    try

        set sel to selection
        if sel is {} then error "The selection  is empty" -- no selection

    on error errTexttwo number errNumtwo
        display dialog "No photos selected " & errNumtwo & return & errTexttwo
        return
    end try

    set imagename to "unknown filename"
    try
        set target to item 1 of sel -- the image to seach for
        tell target
            set imagename to the filename of target
        end tell
    on error errTexttwo number errNumtwo
        display dialog "Cannot get the filename of the first image: " & errNumtwo & return & errTexttwo
    end try
    set resultcaption to (resultcaption & imagename)
end tell

try
    display alert resultcaption buttons {"Cancel", "OK"} as informational giving up after 2
on error errText number errNum
    if (errNum is equal to -128) then
        -- User cancelled.
        return
    end if
end try
-- From Jacques Rioux's script:
tell application "Photos"
    -- set sel to selection
    if sel is {} then return -- no selection
    try
        set thisId to id of item 1 of sel
    on error errText number errNum
        display dialog "Error: cannot get the image ID" & errNum & return & errText & "Trying again"

        try
            delay 2
            set thisId to id of item 1 of sel
        on error errTexttwo number errNumtwo
            display dialog "Skipping image due to repeated error: " & errNumtwo & return & errTexttwo
            error "giving up"
            return
        end try --second attempt
    end try

    set theseNames to {}
    try
        set theseNames to name of (albums whose id of media items contains thisId)
    on error errText number errNum
        display dialog "Error: cannot get the albums" & errNum & return & errText & "Trying again"
        try
            delay 2
            set theseNames to name of (albums whose id of media items contains thisId)
        on error errTexttwo number errNumtwo
            display dialog "Skipping image due to repeated error: " & errNumtwo & return & errTexttwo
            error "giving up"
            return
        end try
    end try
end tell

if theseNames is not {} then
    set {oTid, text item delimiters} to {text item delimiters, return}
    set {t, text item delimiters} to {theseNames as string, oTid}
    -- return oTid
else
    set t to "No album"
end if
activate


set resultcaption to resultcaption & ", found it in these albums:
" & t as string
set the clipboard to resultcaption
display dialog resultcaption buttons {"OK"} default button "OK" -- you can press the Enter key or the return Key to close the dialog
return resultcaption -- léonie
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a different Applescript that I wrote, which works for me. With this you can just select a photo in Photos and run the script, without adding the photo to a new album. I saved it in the scripts folder Photos, so it shows up as a menu item in Photos.

```
tell application "Photos"
    set selectedPhotos to get selection -- Get the selected photo
    try
        if selectedPhotos is {} then error -- No selection
    on error
        display alert "Select a photo, then run this script to find albums containing the photo."
        return
    end try
    -- Find albums that contain the photo's ID
    set selectedPhotoId to get id of first item in selectedPhotos
    set containingAlbums to get albums whose id of media items contains selectedPhotoId
    try
        if containingAlbums is {} then error
    on error
        display alert "That photo is not in any albums"
    end try
    -- Get names of albums and show them
    set albumNames to name of albums whose id of media items contains selectedPhotoId
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ", "
    albumNames as string
    display alert "Albums containing selected photo: " & (albumNames as string)
end tell
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Tom for your script.
It's work, but the script didn't check albums in folders.
Do you know how we can add this in the script ?

I have only found how to list the folders in Photos App :
set folderNames to name of folders
display alert "List of Folders: " & (folderNames as string)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have albums nested in folders in folders.
This script works for me (but could be polished I'm sure)

```
tell application "Photos"
    
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to return
    
    set selectedPhotos to get selection -- Get the selected photo
    try
        if selectedPhotos is {} then error -- No selection
    on error
        display alert "Select a photo, then run this script to find albums containing the photo."
        return
    end try
    -- Find albums that contain the photo's ID
    set selectedPhotoId to get id of first item in selectedPhotos
    set containingAlbums to get albums whose id of media items contains selectedPhotoId
    try
        if containingAlbums is {} then error
    on error
        display alert "That photo is not in any albums"
    end try
    
    -- Get names of albums and show them
    set albumNames1 to name of albums whose id of media items contains selectedPhotoId
    albumNames1 as string
    
    set albumNames2 to name of albums in folders whose id of media items contains selectedPhotoId
    albumNames2 as string
    
    set albumNames3 to name of albums in folders in folders whose id of media items contains selectedPhotoId
    albumNames3 as string
    
    display alert "In Albums: " & return & (albumNames1 as string) & return & (albumNames2 as string) & return & (albumNames3 as string)
end tell
```